# What is the right way of saying this: "we're giving our opinion OF/ABOUT you"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I've done some research but I still don't quite understand the difference between "of" and "about" after the noun "opinion".

Edit: the original sentence is "we're giving our honest opinion OF/ABOUT you". 
I don't know if that changes anything, but a source said "of" is more common when there's an adjective in the sentence.

Comment: Or even "our opinion **on**..." Google's [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opinion+of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Copinion%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bopinion%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOpinion%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows decreasing popularity for "opinion of". Edit: the question update shows that **on** isn't so good here: it is more usual for *topics*.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a *right* way. But when typing "our opinion of you" and "our opinion about you" IMO the first seems more natural.

Comment: Intuitively, I'd give an opinion on or about an issue or topic, and of a person or concrete thing. There isn't a hard and fast difference though because issues and people can overlap.

Answer (score -1):

Good question. It's a slim distinction.

My opinion *of* you usually refers to my overall feelings:

Examples: *I like you. I trust you. I think you're smart.*

My opinion *about* you is usually my more detailed evaluation:

Example: *After working with you for a few days, I've decided that although you don't have much experience, you learn fast and aren't afraid to try new things or improvise.*